# Generate JSON in Google Endpoint with @JsonString annotation

Tags: java, android, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Goal: Generate a JSON string from a Java object that uses the @JsonString annotation inside of a Google Endpoint.

Strategy:

```
public class MyBean {
    @JsonString private Long id;
...

String practicaJson = new Gson.toJson(myBean);
```

Expected result:

```
{"id":"5658091668373504",...
```

Actual result:

```
{"id":5658091668373504,...
```

Context:
I have an Android app and a Google cloud Endpoint. The bean is sent from the end point to the Android client through the endpoint http interface fine. Now, I'm trying to sometimes send the bean through Firebase notifcations. So, I need generate my own json string.

The trick is that the bean in my Google endpoint module is a plain Java class that I wrote. The Android client receives a generated version of that bean from the Google endpoint library. That generated bean has the @JsonString annotation. (The Google endpoint library does that because of a JavaScript compatibility issue that I don't care about.)

So, the json generated with the end point side bean is incompatible with the bean in the Android client. A simple solution seemed to be to simply add the @JsonString annotation to my end point bean. Though, Gson seems to ignore the @JsonString annotation.

Any tips for solving the JSON generation issue are welcome. If there is a smarter way to send the same bean/pojo sometimes through the HTTP transport and sometimes through Firebase notification messages, I'd love to hear that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you need:

```
 {"id":"5658091668373504",...
```

you should change Long to String

```
 @JsonString private String id;
```

When you create Object you can use UUID Random to autogenerate id;

Comment: I don't want to change my field from a Long to a String. I care about the Long type in the code. I don't care what it looks like during transfer. The @JsonString annotation should take care of that (or symmetrically on client and server not take care of it).

The ids are generated by Objectify.